# Смена цвета кнопки в поле инпута

Tags: html, css3

[image: Поле поиска в положении focusout]

[image: Поле поиска в положении focusin]

1-картинка input в состоянии покоя,2-курсор в поле поиска
Проблема заключается в том что у меня теряется кнопка,при активном input.Как поймать событие "курсор в поле поиска" и сменить svg кнопки?

```
[https://codepen.io/chapaikank/pen/dybBQxQ][3]
```

На данный момент у меня так
[image: На данный момент у меня так]

Answer (score 1):

Используйте псевдоклассы, в данном случае focus

http://htmlbook.ru/css/focus

Comment: я знаю про псевдоклассы,решил с помощью addeventlistener  "focus и blur" и сменой стиля у класса active